# Copy from one workbook to another workbook for a range where the last cell in range varies

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another for specific ranges where the last row varies.

I have tried a few different expressions for where 'H', but have defaulted for now as a workaround to the ending of said column to 10000. I am stumped.

```
Sub Copy_Workbook1()
  Workbooks("Raw Bulk Upload report.xlsx").Worksheets("ETPP Bulk Upload").Range("f4:H10000).Copy _
    Workbooks("ETPP Bulk Upload List.xlsm").Worksheets("TCExport").Range("B2")
  Workbooks("Raw Bulk Upload report.xlsx").Worksheets("ETPP Bulk Upload").Range("V4:V100000").Copy _
    Workbooks("ETPP Bulk Upload List.xlsm").Worksheets("TCExport").Range("e2")
  Workbooks("Raw Bulk Upload report.xlsx").Worksheets("ETPP Bulk Upload").Range("AR4:AU100000").Copy _
    Workbooks("ETPP Bulk Upload List.xlsm").Worksheets("TCExport").Range("H2")
  Workbooks("Raw Bulk Upload report.xlsx").Worksheets("ETPP Bulk Upload").Range("AJ4:AJ100000").Copy _
    Workbooks("ETPP Bulk Upload List.xlsm").Worksheets("TCExport").Range("L2")
  Workbooks("Raw Bulk Upload report.xlsx").Worksheets("ETPP Bulk Upload").Range("AX4:AX100000").Copy _
    Workbooks("ETPP Bulk Upload List.xlsm").Worksheets("TCExport").Range("M2")
End Sub
```

Copy data from column ranges where it will go to last cell and then paste to another workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want that [Power Query](https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/the-complete-guide-to-power-query/) cannot do. Use tables and Queries and connections and you should be fine.

Comment: I can't use power query because the destination worksheet has to loaded back into a database that won't allow for it.